# Zuul reverse proxy first request fails

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

#### Setup:

I'm using a Zuul reverse proxy to send requests to two different backend services. I do not require any load balancing for this application. I have only one filter configured, which isn't involved in this process and confirmed not being called. The Zuul `listOfServers` for each service is dynamically populated during runtime using the following code from the server:

```
clientFactory.getClientConfig(SERVICE_ID).set(CommonClientConfigKey.ListOfServers, "https://" + host + ":" + port);`
```

The relevant application.yaml setup is as follows:

```
zuul:
  ignored-services: '*'
  add-proxy-headers: false
  sensitive-headers:

  # Use more descriptive name for the Zuul servlet bypass
  servlet-path: '/large-file-uploads'

  ribbon:
    eager-load:
      enabled: true

  routes:
    serviceone:
      path: /service_one/**
      serviceId: 'service_one'
    servicetwo:
      path: /service_two/**
      serviceId: 'service_two'

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

#### Problem:

After `listOfServers` *should* be set (via code above), the first request to a service returns a status 500 and the server prints a Zuul forwarding error (can be found [here](https://justpaste.it/4x51x)). Any subsequent calls go through as expected. Also, it seems to happen only after the backend service is restarted, though it's not a problem with the service (confirmed via Postman tests).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a read timeout problem, see ryanjbaxter's answer here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3021